# Selenium Unable to Locate Element, but it surely exists

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I tried all solutions on Stackoverflow, however still got the same problem.

I am trying to select a specific option from a dropbox. It looks like this:
[click to see the dropbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQJjz.png)

The HTML that belongs to this dropbox is as follows:

```html
<td ct="GLC" lsdata="{1:'STANDARD'}" id="WD18" class="lsContainerCell lsGLCTopVAlign lsContainerCellVAlign--top  urLayoutDefault--grid" valign="TOP" align="left" style="white-space:normal;"><span id="WD19-r" class="lsField lsField--standalone lsField--explicitwidth lsField--hasellipsis lsField--hashelp lsField--list lsField--focus lsField--interactiontarget" aria-live="assertive" style=""><input id="WD19" ct="CB" lsdata="{2:'WD1A',3:'10',4:'2021\x2f2022',27:'WD17'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}]}" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsField__input" readonly="" value="2021/2022" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-readonly="false" aria-controls="WD1A" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" style="width:150px;" title=""><span id="WD19-btn" class="lsField__help" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" aria-hidden="true" role="button"></span></span></td>
```

Nothing I have tried did work because Selenium can not locate element. I've tried it with By.ID and By.XPATH. Last thing I have tried is this:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[1]/span/span[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")`

But I still got the same error for the thousandth time:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That xpath probably fails, dont use it, use class,id, attributes or text to find element. Try this xpath "//td[@ct='GLC']"

Comment: Why are you using xpath and not By.ID with id=WD18

Comment: @dosas he can use Xpath "//td[@id='WD18']"  and keep going using xpath

Comment: @dosas that's how I started with, does not work.

Comment: @Wonka Xpath instead of Full Xpath does not work as well.

Comment: Could you post a link to the page?

Comment: @dosas It is a log-in based page which I have logged in with my own id and pw, if there is anything I can post else, I'd love to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Xpath, avoid absolute path (click element, get xpath -_-)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@ct='GLC']")
```

Comment: Well, I have started my trials with Xpath, not absolute path. That also does not work.

Comment: Does website have iframes? If we cant see the HTML cant help. Maybe you have to click first the dropbox and then click on one element

Comment: I have also tried that, It cannot locate the button that belongs to the dropbox as well. If there is any way for me to share the whole HTML and if that can help, I may.

Comment: Do "right click" on the right white box of Academic Year, > Inspect, it is probably a input element, take screenshot to see and locate that element. But full access to html helps more

Comment: Right click on this page is not like all other pages. I think this will give an idea about my problem but I, myself have no clue. This is the screenshot of what happens for every right click in the page: https://i.hizliresim.com/3j60u93.png . And the user that writes in the right click menu which starts with 169.. is my id.

Comment: You can always bypass it, open dev tools on browser, go to Inspector , use the "thing" (dont know how to call it) on TOP-LEFT to pick up element (first you have to click that, then click on element, you have to see how html change when you move mouse over elements)

Comment: Also run on Dev-Tools console this --> $x("//iframe") . To check if there are iframe presented, cause there are a lot of things that can cause errors

Comment: Well, I have been using Ctrl + Shift + C for the Inspector window and yes, I can see how html changes when I move my mouse over elements. But still, should not selenium find the element I am trying to get? I've used time.sleep(120) to also inspect the ChromeDriver that opens with my script, copied the Xpath comes from there and it is still unable to find element... I'm about to go crazy